# Cyrillic in TeXShop

Tags: texshop

I have a document with parts of the text in cyrillic, i TeXworks these characters are shown but not in TeXShop, I compile the document in TeXShop and the resulting pdf shows the characters but in the TeXShop screen they are shown as ÐÑÐ°ÑÑÐºÐž Ð¿ÐŸÐºÐ°Ð·ÑÑÑÑ Ð¿ÑÐŸ, I guess that the problem comes from some missing language file in TeXShops but can not go any further

Comment: It looks like the file is in UTF-8 encoding, but TEXShop displays using some 8-bit encoding like ISO8859-1. Can you select the source encoding in TEXShop settings?

Comment: Yes I had Western (ISO Latin 9) changed to Cyrillic (MacOS) but nothing chnaged

Comment: Not to Cyrillic (MacOS), but to UTF-8. Is there unicode support in TeXShop?

Comment: Yes I have UTF-8 but it does not work

Comment: Which latex-engine are you using? I suggest xelatex, which has great UTF-8 support. Try to find the configuration where the pdflatex call is configured and replace pdflatex with xelatex...

Comment: It is the same with xelatex, the problem must be in the configuration of the TeXShop screen, I wrote the file in TeXWorks when I  moved it to TeXShop the cyrillic text was shown with the ÐÑÐ°Ñ characters but the compiled pdf is ok